# Аномалия (если можно так выразиться) с кодировкой

Tags: php, html

Сделал простенький файл с расширением .php и накидал разметку. Кодировка документа UTF-8(без BOM). Но когда вписываю слово "привет" в input[text], то в div отображается "привет", а ниже символ "�". Почему так?! Почему не "п"?

```
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
     <form method="post">
       <input type="text" name="find" autofocus>
       <button>ОК!</button>
     </form>
     <div>
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST['find'])){
         $str = $_POST['find'];
         echo $str . '<br>';
         echo $str[0];
       }
       ?>   
     </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Потому-что `$str[0]` считает строку бинарной (массив байтов). Буква 'п' в UTF-8 кодируется двумя байтами. Вы выводите только первый из них.

Comment: Что нужно сделать, чтобы появилась буква «п»?

Answer (score 1):

Как написали в комментариях, если работать с UTF-8 строкой как с массивом - выводиться будет только 1-й байт (UTF-8 символ занимает 2 байта).
Что-бы вывести 1-й символ UTF-8 строки нужно использовать следующую функцию:

http://www.php.ru/manual/function.mb-substr.html

Пример:

```
echo mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: вынужден продолжить тему... Как быть с условием, например:
'if($str[0] == 'п'){unset (str[0])}'? Ведь я могу не знать, что первая буква в $_POST является "п". Как мне букву "п" записать в условии, если такая проблема с кодировкой?